# jQuery: A button that checks all checkboxes in its own DIV and unchecks all the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a dynamically generated form with groups of checkboxes representing categories of companies. These eventually get plotted on a dynamic chart (not shown here). Each group of companies is in a div, and each div has a button called **Only** that should check all the checkboxes in its own category (div) and uncheck all the other checkboxes on the page.

Here's a Fiddle with all the code: https://jsfiddle.net/c2kn78a9/

The **Only** buttons have this code in them:

```
// Uncheck all checkboxes outside this div
$(this).closest("div").not(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).change();

// Check all checkboxes in this div
$(this).closest("div").find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true).change();
```

But it's not working. Any idea how to fix this?

Here's the code for the entire page.

```
<!-- This button is different than the other buttons -->
<button class="button-text" id="customize-button">Open User Settings</button>

<!-- Placeholder for dynamic form -->
<div id="company-selection-form"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function toMachineString(humanString) {
  var machineString = humanString.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  machineString = machineString.replace('&','');
  return machineString;
}

// Setup the form
var categories = new Map([
  ['Tech Giants',['Alphabet','Amazon','Apple','Facebook','Microsoft']], 
  ['Handset Manufacturers',['Apple','Samsung','Motorola','Sony']],
  ['Semiconductors', ['AMD','Intel','Nvidia']]
  //  ... more ...
  ]);

// Build company selection form inputs
let companySelectionHTML = '';

for (let category of categories) {

  categoryName = category[0];
  categoryList = category[1];

  // Setup a div to differentiate each category of companies.
  // Will be used for turning on/off categories en masse
  companySelectionHTML += `<div id="${toMachineString(categoryName)}">\n`;

  // Category heading
  companySelectionHTML += `<h4>${categoryName}</h4>\n`;

  // Only button
  companySelectionHTML += `<button class="only" id="btn-only-${toMachineString(categoryName)}">Only</button>\n`;

  categoryList.forEach(companyName => {

    companySelectionHTML += `
      <label class="checkbox-label">
          <input id="x-${toMachineString(companyName)}" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="company" value="${companyName}" checked>
          <label for="x-${toMachineString(companyName)}">${companyName}</label>
      </label>`;
  });

  companySelectionHTML += '</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n';
}

// Append to DOM
const companySelectionId = document.getElementById('company-selection-form');
companySelectionId.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', companySelectionHTML);

// Make the ONLY buttons check all the checkboxes in their div and uncheck everything else
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".only", function() {

    // Uncheck all checkboxes outside this div
    $(this).closest("div").not(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).change();

    // Check all checkboxes in this div
    $(this).closest("div").find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true).change();

  });
});

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add your HTML code as well in order to make this question more understandable.

Comment: The HTML code is indeed there. Remember, the form is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.not(this)` is trying to filter out the button element from the single closest div. You need to get all div's on the page and remove the closest div to "this" button.

From your JSFiddle like this:

```
var temp = $(this).closest("div");
$("div").not(temp).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).change();
```

OR (to avoid a new variable)

```
$("div").not($(this).closest("div")).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).change();
```

Comment: I cannot get either example to work. Any chance you could you put this into a Fiddle for testing?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm sorry, I messed it up. It works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Matt G's solution works fine, it deselects all the checkboxes on the page.
I'd suggest to further refine it by first narrowing the selection to only your #company-selection-form

```
  `$("#company-selection-form")
    .find("div")
    .not($(this)
    .closest("div"))
    .find('input[type=checkbox]')
    .prop('checked', false)
    .change();`
```

Nevertheless, allow me to suggest that you're maybe wasting your time learning this stuff. This programming paradigm is too problematic and anachronistic. It's slow, gets out of hand very quickly, and never brings anything but suffering. Even the slightest update to the UI can force you to revisit (after months sometimes), debug, and rewrite your code.  It's never testable, no one would even bother to test this rigorously.

I mean, if your employer holds a gun to your head every day and you have to choose either to do it this way or die, you'd soon choose to die over this ordeal.

Comment: :) You're not wrong. But if you can believe it, this is code being used for a hobby project!